# dependency injection in mvc filter which is global

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

I use unity and then ninject in mvc4, mvc5. 
I inject service or dbcontext to action filter as public property this way:

```
 public class MyActionFilterAttribute: FilterAttribute,IActionFilter
{
    [Inject]
    public IDbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public IProductService ProductService { get; set; }


    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Debug.WriteIf(DbContext == null, "db context is null");
        Debug.WriteIf(ProductService == null, "productservice is null");


    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    { }
}
```

}

If I register a global filter, `filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute());` DbContext and ProductService are always null. 
But if i mark [MyActionFilter] attribute to Controller everything works fine.
I'd like to register some filter as global, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple example is to register your filter globally in the NinjectWebCommon class, you can do like this:

```
kernel.BindFilter<MyActionFilterAttribute>(FilterScope.Global, 1).InRequestScope();
```

and remove the line from Global.asax

Comment: 1. kernel.BindFilter in an extention method in what class? I don't have one. 2. Should I remove global filter.Add ? 3. what line to remove in global.asax?

Comment: 1) You said in your question that you use Ninject, so it uses a class called NinjectWebCommon, that is in App_Start folder usually. In the RegisterServices method you register your binds. 

2) You must remove the filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute()); from your Global.asax

Comment: This way suits me better because i don't touch code in MyActionFilterAttribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Wen you are registering global filters like this `filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute());` you are registering filter instance. This same instance will be used on every call. This instance doesn't have your dependencies populated because you created it yourself using default constructor instead of resolving it from the container. Of course you cant resolve instance of your filter during global filter registration because your dependencies (DbContext for example) need to be scoped per request.

So you have 4 options.

- Decorate all your controllers with the action filter
- Create controller base class, decorate this class with the action filter and then derive all your controllers from this class.
- Use some form of service locator inside your action filter code to resolve your dependencies from the container every time they are needed. Then you can register your filter as a global filter.
- Create custom `IFilterProvider` and resolve your filter from the container in the `GetFilters` method. Then register your provider `FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new MyFilterProvider(diContainer));`

Comment: can't understand the last advice. Please write a short example

Comment: good answer, but yes, example for last option would be welcome